# send action from button in collection view

Tags: ios, button, uicollectionview, pushviewcontroller

I have a query that pulls the 10 nearest objects and displays the title of each in a button in a collection view. What I am trying to do is have an action that opens a new view controller displaying information of the object chosen from the collection view. What I need help with is connecting the chosen object in the buttons action. I am new to Xcode and could use some advice. This is the code defining the query:

```
int i = 0;
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            if (i >= [self.EventTitles count]) break;//to make sure we only write up to the max number of UILabels available in EventTitles
            [(UIButton *)self.EventButtons[i] setTitle:[object objectForKey:@"name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [(UIButton *)self.EventButtons[i] addTarget:self action:(social:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            i++;
                        }
```

And then there is the code with the action

```
- (IBAction)social:(id)sender{

    UIActionSheet *share = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Call",@"Directions",@"Website",@"Checkin", nil];

    [share showInView:self.view];
}


- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    //Each button title we gave to our action sheet is given a tag starting with 0.
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSString* yourActualNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",????????];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourActualNumber]];
        NSLog(@"phone");
        //Check Twitter accessibility and at least one account is setup.

    }
```

I just do not know how to connect the object to the action, and then display that information on the new view controller.

UPDATE: I updated the code with the new line in the query, however it fails stating that the action social is undeclared however it is? I also changed the action to perform an action sheet rather than a new view controller. What I need now it a connection from the object to the action and how to write in the object for key appropriately in the action sheet function.

Comment: **@Selector(social:)**

Answer (score 0):

> What I need help with is connecting the chosen object in the buttons
>   action.

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(DetailEvent1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]

> and then display that information on the new view controller.

I don't really know what you are asking here, if you clarify I'll try my best to help :)

Comment: I updated the code with the new line in the query, however it fails stating that the action social is undeclared however it is? I also changed the action to perform an action sheet rather than a new view controller. What I need now it a connection from the object to the action and how to write in the object for key appropriately in the action sheet function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where an action sheet is displayed when an item is selected. I'm simply using the index path of the selected item, but I assume you have some other data you'd need to save so the Action Sheet delegate can use it.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Call number %d", indexPath.row];

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:(id < UIActionSheetDelegate >)self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:str, nil];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is run a query to show you the 10 closest store locations and when you click on 1 of the buttons in the UIButton collection view it will open an action sheet so that you can have an option to call the location. Hope that helps

Comment: I edited the answer with a simple example.  Don't forget to hook up the UICollectionViewDelegate protocol.